# "Parse Error" when using $_GET variable (PHP)

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a webpage that shows me the contents of an SQL-Database. This works, but now i'm creating a search option that allows for filtering.

I can't seem to get the superglobal `$_GET` to work though, and I always get his error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_GET' (T_VARIABLE)
>   HTML/PHP code:

```
<header>
    <div id="divSearchBar">
        <form name="SearchBar" method="get" action="index.php">
            <input type="text" name="txtSearchBar"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
            <input type="submit" name="sbmAddItem" value="Add Item"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
        <?php
            include_once "Repository.php";

            $r = new Repository();
            $tmp = "";
            if (isset $_GET["txtSearchBar"])
            {
                $tmp = $_GET["txtSearchBar"];   
            }

            $myItems = $r->GetItems(tmp);
            for($i=0;$i<count($myItems);$i++)
            {
                print '<div id="divGen"><p id="pGen">' . $myItems[$i]->Item . '</p><p id="pGen2">' . $myItems[$i]->Category . "</p></div>";
            }
        ?>
</main>
```

Comment: And if ever in doubt, check the manual: http://php.net/isset

Comment: `isset()` need parantheses http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: And you can shorten it to one line using a ternary operator, `$tmp = isset($_GET["txtSearchBar"]) ?  $_GET["txtSearchBar"] : '';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parentheses with the [`isset`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function

```
if (isset($_GET["txtSearchBar"])) // <-- Here
{
    $tmp = $_GET["txtSearchBar"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code to

```
if (isset($_GET["txtSearchBar"]))
{
      $tmp = $_GET["txtSearchBar"];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use isset() function in round brackets

```
<?php
            include_once "Repository.php";

            $r = new Repository();
            $tmp = "";
            if (isset ($_GET["txtSearchBar"]))
            {
                $tmp = $_GET["txtSearchBar"];   
            }

            $myItems = $r->GetItems(tmp);
            for($i=0;$i<count($myItems);$i++)
            {
                print '<div id="divGen"><p id="pGen">' . $myItems[$i]->Item . '</p><p id="pGen2">' . $myItems[$i]->Category . "</p></div>";
            }
        ?>
```